# SonarQube is under maintenance

Tags: sonarqube

I added a new extension plugin for typescript, stop and restarted the service and now the web page sonarqube displays "SonarQube is under maintenance".
On the web they said to try \setup but it does not work...

Someone have an idea of how to remove this maintenance mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you take a look at the server logs? There are great changes that your plugin broke the startup.

Comment: Yes => no error message. The last mesg is: web[o.s.s.app.Logging]  Web server is started

Comment: Please provide the full server logs.

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to enable trace logging in sonar.properties and restart the server (just search for 'TRACE' in sonar.properties file)

Comment: there should be something like this in the sonar.log:  `2018.12.27 19:11:29 WARN  app[][startup]
################################################################################
      Database must be upgraded. Please backup database and browse /setup
################################################################################`

Answer (score 43):

You should update the database if you use MySQL or another RDBMS: Visit http://127.0.0.1:9000/setup. After the update finished，visit http://127.0.0.1:9000. It's ok!

Comment: Thanks for this! The UI directs you to an upgrade page that does not mention /setup and I was very confused for a moment.

Answer (score 6):

Please follow the below steps to upgrade your sonarqube server:

1. First take the backup of your sonarqube server
2. Rename the current sonarqube folder (i.e mv /opt/sonarqube /opt/sonarqube_old)
3. now unzip the latest downloaded setup to /opt/
4. now make the changes in sonar.properties and wrapper.conf file according to old setup.
5. now start the sonarqube service (systemctl start sonar)
6. Now browse http://localhost:9000/setup to upgrade your database
7. After upgrade the database, browse your sonarqube server

Enjoy! your server is upgraded!

Thanks
Sandeep